# TextSpan avoid line break on symbol String group

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a `RichText()` widget with a TextSpan containing a String of symbols such as `€€€€€€€`

this group of symbol is not considered as one word even thought there is no spacing

-> I'd like to avoid a line break to happen between those symbols have to stay together

I can't set `softWrap: false` on `RichText` as I need a line break somewhere to avoid overflow

```dart
RichText(
   text: TextSpan(
      text: 'Random text hello there Random long text',
       children: <TextSpan> [
         const TextSpan(text: ' · '),
         TextSpan(text: '€€€€€€€'),
         ],
   ),
 ),
```

can't I set `softWrap: false` directly on TextSpan or something similar ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

##### Before:

[image]

##### After:

[image]

Use `WidgetSpan` with `Text` instead of `TextSpan`.

```dart
RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    text: 'Random text hello there Random',
    children: [
      const TextSpan(text: ' · '),
      WidgetSpan(
        child: Text('€€€€€€€'),
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set [`TextOverflow.visible`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextOverflow.html) for the respective `TextSpan`, it will force the word to be visible as one word, basically the flutter version of `softWrap: false` but a possible problem can be that it will exceed the available width.

To do that, check this code:

```
RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    text: 'Random text hello there Random long text',
    children: <TextSpan> [
      const TextSpan(text: ' · '),
      TextSpan(
        text: '€€€€€€€', 
        style: TextStyle(
          overflow: TextOverflow.visible,
        )
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Let's see if it works.

Comment: CopsOnRoad's answer is  better but thank you, I've up voted yours too : )

Answer (score 0):

Does an [InlineSpan](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/InlineSpan-class.html) help you?

or adding an "overflow" property to its style: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextOverflow.html like

```
RichText(
  text: TextSpan(
    text: 'Random text hello there Random long text',
    children: <TextSpan> [
      const TextSpan(text: ' · '),
      TextSpan(
        text: '€€€€€€', 
        style: TextStyle(
          overflow: 'visible',
        )
      )
    ]
  )
```

?

Answer (score 0):

**add :-** **softWrap: true**,

**style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),**

```
RichText(
                softWrap: true,
                text: const TextSpan(
                  text: 'Random text hello there Random long text ',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                  children: <TextSpan>[
                    TextSpan(
                        text: 'hello there Random long',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red)),
                    TextSpan(
                        text: '€€€€€€€', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red)),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
```